# Angular/TypeScript - Union type access

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an interface with a property that has a union type:

```
interface Challenge {
  id: number;
  category: Category | string;
}
```

Category interface:

```
Interface Category {
  id: number;
  label: string;
}
```

In my controller i have a `this.challenge` which type`Challenge`.

now from the template I would like to show the `challenge.category.label`:

```
<p>{{ challenge.category.label }}</p>
```

but it does not work because the `label` property does not exist on the string type, and it's the same error if I try to access the property from the controller:

```
getLabel(): string {
  return this.challenge.category.label
}
```

how can I specify that the type of this category instance is `Category`, since the template directly preference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

The easiest solution would be:

```
function getLabel(): string {
  return (<Category>this.challenge.category).label;
}
```

But if you will use this many times it's worth creating a type guard:

```
function getLabel(): string {
  if (isCategory(challenge.category)) {
    return this.challenge.category.label;
  } else {
    // this will be string
    return this.challenge.category;
  }
}

function isCategory(category: Category | string): category is Category {
  return (<Category>this.challenge.category).label !== undefined;
}
```

Comment: Since the `rank` is retrieved via an`@input`, there is no way to force the category type to that location?
`@Input() rank: Rank;`

Comment: @MouadEnnaciri I'm not sure what's the relationship between Challenge and Rank. Can you update the question ?

Comment: I was wrong sorry, it's `@Input() challenge: Challenge;`